# Servlet Get Init-Param

Tags: servlets

How can I that retrieve these two configuration intial parameters name "Regular" and "Premier"

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>StockServelt</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test.StockServelt</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>Premier</param-name>
        <param-value>/Premier</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>Regular</param-name>
        <param-value>/Regular</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

I have try this code and it's giving me a null value

```
final String PREMIER = getServletContext().getInitParameter("Premier");
final String REGULAR = getServletContext().getInitParameter("Regular");
```

Any help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
final String PREMIER = getServletContext().getInitParameter("Premier");
final String REGULAR = getServletContext().getInitParameter("Regular");
```

with

```
final String PREMIER = getServletConfig().getInitParameter("Premier");
final String REGULAR = getServletConfig().getInitParameter("Regular");
```

You have to read the servlet config init params, not servlet context init params.